# nanoScrollbar does not work when mouse wheel used inside the DIV

Tags: jquery, css, scroll

I am trying to make two row css web page layout and fits in the window height available. If the content on bottom div height it should display a scroll-bar using nano scroll. code follows.

When mouse wheel used inside the content div it does not move the nano scroll. Only time it works when you move your mouse on the top of nano scroll and do the scrolling.

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            * {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }

            html, body, .Container, .myContent {
                height: 100%;
            }

                .Container:before {
                    content: '';
                    height: 100%;
                    float: left;
                }

            .HeightTaker {
                position: relative;
                z-index: 1;
            }

            .HeightTaker:after {
                content: '';
                clear: both;
                display: block;
            }

            .Wrapper {
                position: absolute;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
            }

            .myContent {
                overflow: inherit;
                background-color: #66cab7;
                text-align: center;
            }

            .Header {
                background-color: #bf5b5b;
                text-align: center;
            }

            /** nano css **/
            .nano {
                position: relative;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                overflow: hidden;
            }

            .nano .nano-content {
                position: absolute;
                overflow: scroll;
                overflow-x: hidden;
                top: 0;
                right: 0;
                bottom: 0;
                left: 0;
            }

            nano .nano-content:focus {
                outline: thin dotted;
            }

            .nano .nano-content::-webkit-scrollbar {
                visibility: hidden;
            }

            .has-scrollbar .nano-content::-webkit-scrollbar {
                visibility: visible;
            }

            .nano > .pane {
                background: rgba(0,0,0,.25);
                position: absolute;
                width: 10px;
                right: 0;
                top: 0;
                bottom: 0;
                visibility: hidden\9; /* Target only IE7 and IE8 with this hack */
                opacity: .01;
                -webkit-transition: .2s;
                -moz-transition: .2s;
                -o-transition: .2s;
                transition: .2s;
                -moz-border-radius: 5px;
                -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
                border-radius: 5px;
            }

            .nano > .pane > .slider {
                background: #444;
                background: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
                position: relative;
                margin: 0 1px;
                -moz-border-radius: 3px;
                -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
                border-radius: 3px;
            }

            .nano:hover > .pane, .pane.active, .pane.flashed {
                visibility: visible\9; /* Target only IE7 and IE8 with this hack */
                opacity: 0.99;
            }
        </style>
        <script src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2781659/js/jquery-2.0.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2781659/js/jquery.nanoscroller.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                $(".nano").nanoScroller();
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="Container">
            <div class="Header">
                <h1>Header</h1>
                <p>if The Header height is not fixed, It will span excatly his needed space.</p>
                <p>The Padding/Margin between the header and the content and around the layout is optional</p>

            </div>
            <div class="HeightTaker">
                <div class="Wrapper">
                    <div class="nano">
                        <div class="content myContent">
                            <h1>Content</h1>
                            <p>The Content div should always span the available Container space.</p>
                            <p>If the content exceed the Content available space, it will scroll.</p>
                            <p><a target="_blank" href="http://jsfiddle.net/avrahamcool/58mkp/">Here's a demo of this scenario</a></p>
                            <p class="Important">This Layout has been tested on: IE10, IE9, IE8, FireFox, Chrome, Safari, Opera. using Pure CSS 2.1 only</p>
                            test<br />
                            test<br />
                            test<br />
                            test<br />
                            test<br />
                            test<br />
                            test<br />
                            test<br />
                            test<br />
                            test<br />
                            test<br />
                            test<br />
                            test<br />
                            test<br />
                            test<br />
                            test<br />
                            test<br />
                            test<br />
                            test<br />
                            test<br />
                            test<br />
                            test<br />
                            test<br />
                            test<br />
                            test<br />
                            test<br />
                            test<br />
                            test<br />
                            test<br />
                            test<br />
                            test<br />
                            test<br />
                            test<br />
                            test<br />
                            test<br />
                            test<br />
                            test<br />
                            test<br />
                            test<br />
                            test<br />
                            test<br />
                            test<br />
                            test<br />
                            test<br />
                            test<br />
                            test<br />
                            test<br />
                            test<br />
                            test<br />
                            test<br />
                            test<br />
                            test<br />
                            test<br />
                            test<br />
                            test<br />
                            test<br />
                            test<br />
                            test<br />
                            test<br />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Applying `overflow: inherit;` to myContent works, but only scrolls by mouse click.

Comment: Thanks Anup, but I cannot use this solution because I cannot restrict user to drag mouse on the on the scrollbar to keep working. Appreciate your help though

Answer (score 0):

I think, You need to use jscrollpane js. Try this js.

http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/